# SQLite : What happens if you CREATE INDEX without the FTS module?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, indexing

My current platform is limited to [SQLite without the full text search](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/26630) (FTS) module compiled in. I plan to shift my technology to another platform (C#) in the near future. I don't want to change my DB schema at that point in time.

So I want to create indices for my string columns, even though my current SQLite does not include FTS. When I switch platforms, can a simple [REINDEX](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_reindex.html) command cause all my string columns to index properly? If not, then I'll have to CREATE INDEX when switching platforms. This will be difficult for me due to the characteristics of my app.

Answer (score 0):

An FTS index is not a 'real' index; it is a virtual table created with the [CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE statement](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createvtab.html).

So you have to run the appropriate CREATE INDEX or CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE statements for each platform.
If you do not want to change the DB schema, you have to use the same indexes on both platforms.

Comment: So can I CREATE INDEX without FTS? or not?